# Macro to convert intext notes to endnotes in MS Word

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am trying to figure a way to convert intext notes (notes and references within the text body) to endnotes in an MS Word document that has existing endnotes and this is my first macro in decades.
My intext notes can be identified since they are in dark blue between curled brackets. So far I managed to record a macro for the single steps: Search for pattern, cut pattern, insert endnote, paste pattern, search pattern again in endnotes, remove curled brackets, focus back to the beginning of the document (out of endnotes).

Here is how it looks:

```
Sub inline2endnote()
Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
Selection.Find.Font.Color = 6299648
Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
With Selection.Find
    .Text = "\{(*?)\}"
    .Replacement.Text = "\1"
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = True
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchWildcards = True
End With
Selection.Find.Execute
Selection.Cut
With Selection
    With .EndnoteOptions
        .Location = wdEndOfDocument
        .NumberingRule = wdRestartContinuous
        .StartingNumber = 1
        .NumberStyle = wdNoteNumberStyleArabic
    End With
    .Endnotes.Add Range:=Selection.Range, Reference:=""
End With
Selection.PasteAndFormat (wdFormatOriginalFormatting)
Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
Selection.Find.Font.Color = 6299648
Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
With Selection.Find
    .Text = "\{(*?)\}"
    .Replacement.Text = "\1"
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = True
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchWildcards = True
End With
Selection.Find.Execute
With Selection
    If .Find.Forward = True Then
        .Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseStart
    Else
        .Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
    End If
    .Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceOne
    If .Find.Forward = True Then
        .Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
    Else
        .Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseStart
    End If
    .Find.Execute
End With
Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory
End Sub
```

I had to focus back on top because I needed to exit the endnotes section and go back to body text. Also, I have no idea what the last "With" section is meant to do. 
Now I would like to loop this pattern in order to fix all the inline notes, but I seem unable to find away. I was using [this thread](https://community.endnote.com/t5/EndNote-How-To/Converting-in-text-citations-to-footnotes-endnotes/td-p/4438) as a reference but I can't figure out how to properly set my scope and define the fields for my iterations.
I was also wondering if there is a cleaner way to write the steps, like pasting my content without curled brackets directly, like store my find in a variable and use a second one with stripped content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
Sub Demo()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim Rng As Range, E_Nt As Endnote
With ActiveDocument.Range
  With .Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Text = "\{[!\{]@\}"
    .Font.Color = 6299648
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindStop
    .Format = True
    .MatchWildcards = True
    .Execute
  End With
  Do While .Find.Found
    Set Rng = .Duplicate
    With Rng
      .Start = .Start + 1
      .End = .End - 1
    End With
    Set E_Nt = .Endnotes.Add(.Duplicate)
    E_Nt.Range.FormattedText = Rng.FormattedText
    E_Nt.Range.Font.ColorIndex = wdAuto
    .Text = vbNullString
    .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
    .Find.Execute
  Loop
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Wow, it is  extremely efficient and fast! I had barely managed to loop the Do while .Find.Found but it could not then strip the brackets in endnotes. The problem is that it will create an endnote for all text in curled brakets and not just for the blue one and I cannot understand why.

Comment: Code updated. As simple as changing '.Format = False' to '.Format = True'.

Comment: Thank you, it worked. May I ask where I can find references to the regex you used for search? I can see it avoid nested curled brackets, which is something I will need to take care, by I have found nothing about the @ except it bein used as literal in email addresses.